# How to specify a android app as a callback url

Tags: android, xamarin, callback, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have a android app which have a button. When I click the button it opens a link. Link opens a barcode reader and reader sends a callback to URL. But since I don't have an website. I need to specify my android app as a callback url.

This link has a information about it. How can i return data to my app with this callback URL?
https://ioshelp.qrbot.net/xcallback

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: Why not just scan the QR inside of the App?

Comment: ios help? are you trying to use something for ios on android?

Comment: I have solved it with Thommy's answer.

@Cheesebaron Because most of the free libraries for android like zxing library dont scan 2-3 meters away.